# How can I fix a merge conflict from the Github website?

Tags: git, github, git-merge-conflict

I was on a branch called `make-monolith-ids-constant`.

I ran these commands in the terminal.

```
git checkout make-monolith-ids-constant
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master
```

I now have a merge conflict I'm trying to resolve on the website and this is all that shows up.

```
<<<<<<< make-monolith-ids-constant
                            @link-click="setAddPreviewText"
=======
>>>>>>> master
```

If I would like to keep only the changes from the master branch what would I delete here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing are Git's merge conflict markers, which have been inserted into the source file, pending resolution.  The following code given reads as:

```
<<<<<<< make-monolith-ids-constant
                            @link-click="setAddPreviewText"
=======
>>>>>>> master
```

In the parent branch `make-monolith-ids-constant`, there is the following code:

```
@link-click="setAddPreviewText"
```

In the `master` branch, this does *not* appear.  So, you need to decide whether or not you want to keep this line.  In your local `make-monolith-ids-constant` branch, delete the `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>` markers, leaving behind either that line, or not line at all.

Then, `git add` this source file, commit, and then push your `make-monolith-ids-constant` branch back to GitHub:

```
git push origin make-monolith-ids-constant
```

Comment: This seemed to work. Thank you!

Comment: @HailVelkekia While editing those conflict markers manually sort of works, **what you really, really want is to use a proper graphical 3-way merge tool** (e.g. a tool that presents you with *four* panes with input & output). [KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) is an excellent such tool.

Comment: @hlovdal Sort of.  In most cases, I might prefer a 3-way tool, but I also find there are scenarios where I would rather do it manually.

Comment: I'll be sure to take a look at that. Seems useful.